# htaccess rewrite redirect with parameters in subfolder

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

I want that when you go to url:
http://www.example.com/subdir/paramvalue

redirects to

http://www.example.com/subdir/index.php?param=paramvalue

My .htaccess file is:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)   subdir/index.php?param=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But does not work. How can i do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place this rule in `subdir/.htaccess` (not site root):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php?param=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: I had already .htaccess in subdir/.htaccess, i put this but does not work.

Comment: http://www.example.com/subdir/paramvalue and the error is Not Found
The requested URL /subdir/paramvalue was not found on this server.
Apache Server at www.example.com Port 80

Comment: Verify whether your `.htaccess` is enabled or not, by putting some garbage (random) text on top of your `.htaccess` and see if it generates 500 (internal server) error or not when you visit `http://www.example.com/subdir/paramvalue` page in browser. 500 error means .htaccess is enabled.

Comment: No, it is not enabled, how can i enable it ? The error is still 404

Comment: ok then you will need to enable it first. Every Apache installation has different instructions. Better you search for instructions on Google for your OS.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks anubhava !
First i edit 000-default from /etc/apache2/sites-available/ and add:

```
<Directory "/var/www">
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

Then the solution in .htaccess was:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /subdir/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?param=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Finally in /subdir/index.php

I get the value paramvalue as:

```
$myParamValue = $_GET["param"];
echo myParamValue
```

it returns :
paramvalue